# Is there any substitution to wizard control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, wizard

we can attain the same effect using tables what is the benefit of wizard control over them

Comment: This wizard control is a data management and display tool, whereas tables are just a way of displaying "tabular" data.  You are comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a MultiPage and managing the navigation yourself are alternatives too; can even just use panels are replacements.

The wizard is just a specialized implementation; if you like something else, use it.  It has events, properties, that are part of the API to represent the core wizard...  It's perfectly OK to not use it too.  Whatever works for you.

HTH.

Comment: that's all right thanks brian & ck but is there anything special about this control so i prioritize it over other method

Comment: It renders the wizard steps on the right, and has views for each mode, and events that drive it accordingly.  That's it.  Additionally, it renders each view in the UI, where some of the other alternatives do not.